# Application routes not working

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've just written some routes (`app\routes.php`) based on Laravel framework as following,

```
    Route::model('cat', 'Cat');
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return "All cats";
    });

    Route::get('/cats', function()
    {
        $cats = Cat::all();
        return View::make('cats.index')->with('cats', $cats);
    });

    Route::get('/cats/breeds/{name}', function($name)
    {
        $breed = Breed::whereName($name)->with('cats')->first();
        return View::make('cats.index')->with('breed', $breed)->with('cats', $breed->cats);
    });

    Route::get('/cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat)
    {
        return View::make('cats.single')->with('cat', $cat);
    });

    Route::get('/cats/create', function()
    {
        return "Cat created.";
    });
```

All routes are okay, except the one `/cats/create`. 
I've tried to create other two dummies routes `/dogs` and `/dogs/xxx`, and the second one (`/dogs/xxx`) is not working.

It sounds weird but it actually happens. Has anyone face this problem before? Or you can provide me some hints to workout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to put `Route::get('/cats/create'` before `Route::get('/cats/{cat}`. Right now system considers your `create` a `{cat}`.

Comment: oh man, so I need to make the right order for registering all my routes.